# How to automatically zoom on Flutter WebView

Tags: flutter, dart, iframe, webview, zooming

I would like to know how to automatically zoom on Flutter WebView.

I know the user can manually zoom on the WebView content, but I would like to control it from the start because when I put the emulator in portrait mode the informations in my WebView are too small for the user to read :

[image]

I tried to increase the WebView width to make it larger and so that it would automatically be zoomed and the user could use horizontal scroll to read it.

```
 child: WebView(
                          zoomEnabled: true,
                          initialUrl: Uri.dataFromString('<html><body><iframe src="webpage_url" width="1920" height="700"></iframe></body></html>', mimeType: 'text/html').toString(),
                          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                        ))
```

This works well with the IFrameElement that I use for the web version of my app (WebView isn't supported by Flutter Web nor is IFrameElement by the android emulator)

```
IFrameElement _iframeElement = IFrameElement();
    _iframeElement.height = '750';
    _iframeElement.width = '1920';
```

Here(web version of my app), the iframe is automatically zoomed accordingly to the width and I height I defined for it :

[image]

How do I achieve that using WebView ?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve this by injecting a [meta viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag) (if not already present) with _controller.runJavascript('your js code');

```
var flutterViewPort=document.createElement('meta');
flutterViewPort.name = "viewport";
flutterViewPort.content = "width=400, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(flutterViewPort);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just put the meta tag in header of the HTML file of string. If you don't have the head tag in your html file then you have to create the basic html structure. After that you have to put the meta tag inside the head tag just like below. And put all other tags in body

```
 <html>
      <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      </head>
    
     <body>
       <p style="color:#D1D1D1;"> Hello world </p>
     </body>

 </html>
```